# program prints some random null line

Tags: c

I'm writing a program in C which, given the interval of integers [a-b], prints the int number of all the values between 1-9 in the interval, and for all the values >9 it only prints weather they're even or odd, i know the code is probably unreadable for an experienced programmer

I tried running it and messing around a bit and after the last integer is printed (9) and the "even" or "odd" has to be printed, i get a null output, and i have no idea why its happening

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d\n%d", &a, &b);
    char *nums[9] = {"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};

    for(int i = 0; (i+a) <= b; i++){
        if(1 <=(a+(i-1)) && 9 >=(a+(i-1))){
            printf("%s\n", nums[(a+(i-1))]);
        } else if (((a+(i-1))%2)==1) {
            printf("odd\n");
        } else {
            printf("even\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: Array indicies start at 0.

Comment: time spent learning to use a debugger is never wasted, but failing that... why don't you print a and b and return from scanf

(scanf is pretty horrible...)

Comment: Also, there is no reason to use the weird and unreadable `(a+(i-1))` all the time. Just count from `a` to `b` rather than from `0` to `b-a`.

Comment: It would make it easier if you have ten elements, the first (unused) being `"nought"` or `"zero"`. Then the index won't need adjusting, whereas now it fails on entry `1`  to `9` by omitting `1`.

Comment: If you want to print the name of the number and if it is even or odd you'll need to split the logic up. First check if the number is in the right range, print the name, then check if it is even or odd and print that.

Comment: OT: `scanf("%d\n%d", &a, &b);` can be `scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);` . Be wary of sprinkling the format string with newlines: they are *significant* although here redundant, because `%d` filters leading whitespace automatically.

Comment: This seems like a very good time to learn how to use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems), and use it to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values. To make it simpler, I recommend you use temporary variables to store intermediate results so they are easier to see. For example you do `i - 1` quite often, store its result in a variable. Then add `a` to that variable and store in yet another variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error in the code appears when the number `10` appears in the given interval.

Inside the `for`, the first `if` is checking if `a+i` minus 1 is less equal than 9.

If `a+i` happens to be 10, such as if the given interval is [10-12] and `i=0`, the condition evaluates to true, because:

`1 <= a+i-1` is equivalent to `1 <= 10+0-1` which is true and
`9 >= a+i-1` is equivalent to `9 >= 10+0-1` which is also true.

In this case, you will be printing `nums[(a+(i-1))]`, which is equivalent to `nums[10+0-1]` which is `nums[9]`, and since your array only has 8 elements, it may trigger the segmentation fault error, stopping the execution immediately.

Depending on where you are seeing the output, this error might seem like it just printed a random null line, but it's actually a run time error of your program.

Notice that such a thing happens whenever `a+i` is 10, which happens when 10 is in the given interval.

Also in the second if, because it also has the minus 1 in it, it would print `even` for odd numbers and vice-versa.

I've changed your code trying to leave your syntax untouched:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d\n%d", &a, &b);
    char *nums[9] = {"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};

    for(int i = 0; (i+a) <= b; i++){
        if(1 <=(a+i) && 9 >=(a+i)){
            printf("%s\n", nums[(a+(i-1))]);
        } else if (((a+i)%2)==1) {
            printf("odd\n");
        } else {
            printf("even\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop to iterate through the range of integers from a to b, printing the numbers and handling special cases for values less than 9 or even/odd numbers. Here's a modified version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

    char *nums[9] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};

    for (int i = a; i <= b; ++i) {
        if (i >= 1 && i <= 9) {
            printf("%s\n", nums[i - 1]);
        } else if (i % 2 == 0) {
            puts("even");
        } else {
            puts("odd");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You're using `scanf("%d\n%d", &a, &b);`, but the newline character '\n' is not necessary and can cause unexpected behaviour. You can simply `scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);`

In this code we use a for loop to iterate through the integers from a to b. For values less than 9, we print the corresponding text using the nums array. For values greater than or equal to 9, we determine whether they are even or odd and print "even" or "odd".

This code should produce the desired output for the given input range [a, b]

Answer (score 0):

This also addresses the "even" and "odd" outputs which I found to be reversed in testing.   Hope it helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    int a, b;
    char *nums[9] = {"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};

    scanf("%d\n%d", &a, &b);

    for(int i = 0; (i+a) <= b; i++)
    {
        int offset = a+(i-1);    /* Added */
        if(0 <= offset && 8 >= offset)  /* Updated: 0 and 8 are the array bounds */
        {
            printf("%s\n", nums[offset]);
        } 
        else 
            if (((offset+1)%2)==1)  /* Updated: even offsets relate to odd numbers(!) (see nums[] array)*/
            {
                printf("odd\n");
            } 
            else 
            {
                printf("even\n");
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```